# Find entity based on one column referencing another and support pagination

Tags: postgresql

I'm dealing with transactions in my system where a transaction goes through two phases, authorization and then capture. This corresponds to two rows in my DB, one authorization row and one capture row. Some transactions are just in their authorization stage and don't have a capture yet. An authorized and later captured transaction is seen as "one" entity, even though there are two rows for it.

My problem: How do I fetch X amount of transactions (entities) so that I can support pagination with OFFSET?

```
+---------+------------------+--------------+------------------------+
| tx_id   | previous_tx_id   | event_type   | timestamp              |
|---------+------------------+--------------+------------------------|
| a       | <null>           | auth         | 2020-01-01 00:00:00+01 |
| b       | a                | capture      | 2020-01-02 00:00:00+01 |
| c       | <null>           | auth         | 2020-01-03 00:00:00+01 |
| d       | <null>           | auth         | 2020-01-04 00:00:00+01 |
| e       | c                | capture      | 2020-01-05 00:00:00+01 |
+---------+------------------+--------------+------------------------+
```

so if I specify

size = 2, I would expect to get the rows with `tx_id`s: `e`, `d`, and `c`. I get both `e` and `c` because they are one *entity*. (and they're the latest ones based on timestamp)

size = 3, I expect rows with `tx_id`s: `e`, `d`, `c`, `b`, and `a`, because `e` and `c` is one entity, `b` and `a` is one entity, `d` is one entity.

Comment: Please explain what size means. Also with size = 2 why would you get the entity e,c but not b,a as both fit the criteria for being "one". You even state that is true  in size=3.

Comment: Because it fetches the latest two entities, so e and c is the latest entity, based on the timestamp. The next one is d.